# how to use Python to detect a cycle in a dictionary

Tags: python

For example:

```
{1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 1, 9: 6}
```

> 1:5>5:6>6:7>7:1, so there is a cycle in this dictionary

How to find out this cycle?

And give me the value appeared in the cycle, which is:

```
[1, 5, 6 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dic = {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 1, 9: 6}

seen = []
k = 1
while k not in seen and k is not None:
    seen.append(k)
    k = dic.get(k)

result = seen[seen.index(k):] if k is not None else []
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer this question, I will spend some time to understand it.

Comment: @Vinsonz No problem :) As for the studying material, if you want to understand algorithms better, there is a great site called Project Euler at https://projecteuler.net, where you can practice by solving various problems.

Comment: This answer won't work if `1` is not connected to the cycle ie. if the dict contains more than one disjoint graph. For example if you try the code with `dic = {1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 10, 9: 6, 12: 12}` it says there are no cycles.